# Firebase Cloud Message Sending Notification through phone

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I figured how to send and receive Firebase Push notifications using Firebase Cloud Messaging[image]

I want to know **how to send a notification manually using code in android studio** so I can send it from any phone.

Comment: you can use firebase functions see example https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/master/fcm-notifications

Comment: It is **strongly advised not to send messages from a client device** when using FCM. This is because you will have to store the *Server Key* on the client side, which is not it's proper usage, and may be exposed and taken advantage of by unauthorized users.

Answer (score 1):

You send messages from your phone using FCM. You need to make a `POST` to `https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send` api with payload that you want to send, and you server key found in Firebase Console project.

As an exameple of payload sending to a single user with `to` param:

```
{ "data": {
      "score": "5x1",
      "time": "15:10"
  },
  "to" : "bk3RNwTe3H0:CI2k_HHwgIpoDKCIZvvDMExUdFQ3P1..."
}
```

Also, `to` param can be used for topics `"to": "topics/yourTopic"`

In `data` you can send whatever you want, message is received in `onMessageReceived()` service from Firebase.

More details you can found in Firebase [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/send-message).